# Python selenium Can't access cookies

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to access a webpage using python, selenium and phantomjs. I get the page using `driver.get` and login to page. It said that I should enable cookies for that.

So I tried accessing cookies like:

```
self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])
self.driver.get('https://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/homepage.html')

cks = self.driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in cks:
    print cookie
    print cookie['name'] + ' - ' + cookie['value']
```

But all I can see in terminal is an empty list. But When I go to that page using mozilla firefox,  multiple cookies are set for that domain.

How can I access those cookies and set them for the webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are enabled by default with PhantomJS, so I don't think there is anything wrong with what you're doing.

I believe the issue lies with Amazon not supporting "Phantomjs/(..*)" in the useragent. Have you tried other site's with this code? When you say you've tried it with FireFox, is that through `webdriver.Firefox()`?

You could try to customise the useragent;

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"
)
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
```

[Docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) for this.

But you should try to run this through `webdriver.Firefox()` to see if it works, then potentially read the `webdriver.Firefox()` useragent & attempt to switch your `webdriver.PhantomJS()` useragent to that used by Firefox.

Comment: No I didn't used firefox from webdriver. I used the browser firefox and checked the cookies in its console. How can I use phantonjs with amazon since all my script are in phantomjs, I would prefer to use it for amazon. Can I change the useragent while using phantomjs with selenium?

Comment: @ManishGupta you should try `webdriver.Firefox()`, if only to prove that it's what Amazon do when sniffing the useragent. Then give the rest of what I've added to my answer a go.

Comment: I used this useragent on windows `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1` and it works but on linux it doesn't. Then I used my linux user agent `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0` and it still is not working. I need to make it work in linux because I will be using an ubuntu server for my scripts deployment.

Comment: @ManishGupta have you tried it with Firefox yet? Then at least you can be sure the issue is that Amazon won't provide cookies to PhantomJS?

Comment: I did now it is throwing me `How to fix Selenium WebDriverException: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect?'

Comment: Also the same script works fine in windows environment.